# Definition of a closed ideal in a $C^*$ algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, functional-analysis, ideals, c-star-algebras

Let $A$ be a commutative and unital $C^*$-algebra. What is the definition of a closed ideal of $A?$

My understanding:

A subset $I$ of $A$ is an **ideal** if it is a vector subspace of $A$ and for any $a$ in $A$ and any $i \in I,$ we have that $a \cdot i \in I$.

A subset $I$ of $A$ is a **closed ideal** if it is an ideal and it is closed in the topology induced by the norm on $A.$

**Question**: Is my definition correct or does a closed ideal need to also be closed under the star operation?

**Bonus question:** Is the quotient space $A/I$ also a commutative and unital $C^*$ algebra?

Thank you for all your help.

Comment: Yes, that's the definition. You would add "two-sided" in front for the non-commutative case. Those will be closed by the involution. You construct [approximate identities](https://www.math.dartmouth.edu/~dana/bookspapers/cstar.pdf#page=51) $e_i\in I$. Then if $a\in I$, then $ae_i\to a$ implies $e_ia^*\to a^*$. Since $e_i\in I$ then $e_ia^*\in I$ and since $I$ is closed, then $a^*\in I$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I found [answers to my questions here.](http://www.math.uvic.ca/faculty/putnam/ln/C*-algebras.pdf)

Namely, the definition of an ideal does not require an ideal to be closed under the star operation. However, whenever $I$ is a (topologically) closed (two-sided) ideal, one can show that $I$ is also closed under the star operation. Also, one can show that $A/I$ is also a $C^*$ algebra.